# Remove jQuery from a specific magento CMS page

Tags: jquery, xml, magento-1.9

I want to remove jQuery 2.1.1 instance from a CMS page, instead of removing it from all pages. I tried like this http://prnt.sc/f2sidy but nothing happened, jquery is still there in the page. Please let me know how can i do that.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If jquery-2.1.1.min.js is located at root/skin/js/ then use

```
 <reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js</name></action>
</reference>
```

and if the js file located at root/js/jquery/ then use

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js</name></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: Thanks @aziz please confirm where should i add this xml, because i tried adding it like here http://prnt.sc/f3b09n but nothing changed. Please advise

Comment: could you confirm how actually you are adding this to the page, are you using layout or template(header.phtml). If you added the js file within template files then you can't remove it using xml layout.

Comment: the js is added inside page.xml

Comment: oh! its my mistake, you don't have to add the <cms_page> tag when you are adding it from cms page layout. I will edit my answer, please try that.

Comment: the confusion remains where should i add these lines. TY

Comment: In same place where you added in the screen shots you provided, inside cms page's design > Layout update XML

Comment: Hi @aziz no luck with this, nothing changed. The jquery is still showing. My juqery is on path "skin/frontend/sm_market/default/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js". PLease advise further, is there any way to remove it in the template file(.phtml).

Comment: If the js is added using layout in head block then the above code should work fine. Please make sure that you are adding the js file in head block and not adding it somewhere else.
And other thing to notice is that you have to publish the CMS page every time you make changes to it, just saving the page won't work.